# How to populate a table from data in JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to populate an HTML table from data that is in a two-dimensional array. The data is coming to an $.ajax script from a php/MySQL query. I'm successfully parsing the data in the success function and I can read out the array element contents to the console, but I can't figure out why the values won't populate the HTML table.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eventide/127dfztf/2/) for my work.

In the console I can populate the input in any of the table cells with this jQuery notation:

```
$('#tblApTdms tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(3) input').val('q34rfewa')
```

but it won't populate in the jsFiddle, in the Web application I'm building, nor in an isolated test page.

I must be missing something here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting parenthesis around the addition equations:

```
$('#tblApTdms tr:nth-child(' + (r + 1) + ') td:nth-child(' + (c + 1) + ') input').val(note);
```

Comment: That works (I'll mark it as the answer when it'll let me), but when I copy/pasted that working code from jsFiddle to my bare-bones, isolated test page, the cells aren't populating. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not sure. Is your test page similar to the jsfiddle?

Comment: The test page has just the jQuery reference, the html and the javascript. Weird - and frustrating!

Comment: Have you looked at the console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: I got it: I copy/pasted the code to an area outside of the jQuery function. Whew!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parens:

```
    $('#tblApTdms tr:nth-child(' + (r + 1) + ') td:nth-child(' + (c + 1) + ') input').val(note);
```

Without the parens, it thinks you're trying to append strings, since that is the prior context.